# Access private data type in base class if only private function exist

Tags: c++, inheritance, private

Given the code below, we can access private data of base class if the function in base are protected by using inheritance. My question is, is there any way we can access private data if all methods in base class are also set to private?

```
class Base

{
int i;

protected:
  void set(int data){
      i = data;
  }
  int get(){
      return i;
  }
};

class derive: Base{
public:
    void change(int x){
        set(x);
        cout<<get()<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   derive b;
   b.change(3);
   return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Err, no, because nobody else can call them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"we can access private data of base class if the function in base are protected by using inheritance", no you're not really accessing private data. You're invoking a setter in the base class that does it for you. And no you won't be able to call the private methods of your base class.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. So there is no way to access private data if both data and function are private? I have been asked this question in an interview and I said no way to do that. But judging from the interviewer's response, I guess there are some tricky methods to realize it.

Comment: If it's was a "trick question" though there IS a way to do it by adding `friend class derive;` in the Base class definition, but it's pure evil.

Comment: And interviewers shouldn't ask 'trick questions'. But if he didn't like your answer you should ask him for his, and evalute it. He could be wrong.

Comment: I never thought using friend class derive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the members to private in the base class will make it private for all children as well. You can define new public functions to change these members in the children.

Answer (score 0):

By using `friend`
Making the derive class the friend of Base

```cpp
class derive;//forward declaration
class Base
{
int i;

private:
  void set(int data){
      i = data;
  }
protected:
  int get(){
      return i;
  }
public:
  friend class derive;
};

class derive : public Base{
public:
    void change(int x){
        set(x);
        cout<<get()<<endl;
    }
};
```

You should be aware of public/protected inheritance. `class a : public/protected b`

Do not use access specifier overloading/overriding:

- [C++: overriding public\private inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753833/c-overriding-public-private-inheritance)
- http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/116-adding-changing-and-hiding-members-in-a-derived-class/

Now I show how to redeclare the access specifier of an inherited member:

```
class derive : public Base{
public:
    Base::set;//this is valid redeclaration within public scope. Now anybody could use derive::set(x)
    void change(int x){
        set(x);
        cout<<get()<<endl;
    }
}
```